# Get output based on the values of one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the column and data is like this

```
|   ID  |   Prop    |   Value   |   String      |
|   1   |   C       |   1       |   NULL        |
|   1   |   Notes   |   NULL    |   TestNote    |   
|   1   |   E       |   59      |   NULL        |
|   1   |   Notes   |   NULL    |   Note2       |
|   2   |   C       |   1       |   NULL        |
```

What I'm trying to do is get both the Notes and C rows on the Prop column

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop IN ("C", "Notes")
```

The output of this is

```
|   ID  |   Prop    |   Value   |   String      |
|   1   |   C       |   1       |   NULL        |
|   2   |   C       |   1       |   NULL        |
```

It only outputted one column. This is the same output when I use 'OR'

Then I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop = "C" AND Prop = "Notes"
```

But i got an empty result, If i do separate select statements like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop = "C"
```

And then do another one on a separate window

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop = "Notes"
```

It works but not how I need it to work.

The output I'm hoping to get is like this:

```
|   ID  |   Prop    |   Value   |   String      |
|   1   |   C       |   1       |   NULL        |
|   1   |   Notes   |   NULL    |   TestNote    |   
|   1   |   Notes   |   NULL    |   Note2       |
|   2   |   C       |   1       |   NULL        |
```

Any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop IN ("C", "Notes")` This should work.

Comment: @Mihai is the problem the double quotes?

Comment: this only gets the C rows and is not getting the "Notes" column

Comment: @McAdam331 Nope,it should work,double or single quotes.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I know this may sound like a dumb question, but are you positive 'notes' has the right spelling in your data?

Comment: Try to TRIM you might have white spaces in there `SELECT * FROM table WHERE TRIM(Prop) IN ("C", "Notes")`

Comment: @sleepingdragon90731 I suppose if all else fails you can hack it by doing a `UNION` between the two select statements that do work, although you shouldn't have to.

Comment: "This is the same output when I use 'OR'" er, no it isn't

Comment: @Strawberry i got the same result when i used or

Comment: @McAdam331 i'll try union

Comment: @sleepingdragon90731 Prove it

Comment: @McAdam331 I used union and it worked exactly how I wanted it. Thank you

Comment: @sleepingdragon90731 Glad it worked, no idea why your statement wouldn't, because it should.

Comment: yea i tried to do a sqlfiddle with the sample data that i provided here and the IN and OR worked. I'm not sure though why its not working on my actual table, anyway thanks for suggesting UNION its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using "OR" in Between ?

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop = 'C' OR Prop = 'Notes'
```

Comment: this only gets the C rows

Comment: The problem are the double quotes, replace with single quotes and your first query with `IN()` condition will give expected output

Comment: @Fabio No they are not the problem

Comment: check if you have same capital case/small case letters, i mean case sensitivity isnt the issue?

Comment: @abdulbasit It's worth checking but SQL (or at least MySQL) is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `Prop = "C" AND Prop = "Notes"` will never be true and so will not work.

The below query as posted should work just fine

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop IN ("C", "Notes")
```

If it's not working then it may be the case that the values are case sensitive.

Use `LOWER()` function along in your query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(Prop) in ('c','notes');
```

(OR) as a alternative use  `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop = 'C' 

UNION

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Prop = 'Notes'
```